# Need to read a user's certificate from the AD userCertificate property

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need a query for Microsoft Graph that will return a given user's encryption certificate.  This would be the certificate stored in the Active Directory `userCertificate` property and the same one that Outlook uses to encrypt SMIME messages

Answer (score 1):

`userCertificate` is not an attribute that is available for users through the Microsoft Graph at the time of writing.